# Load properties file external to webapp in Jetty

Tags: jetty

I have a webapp which I deploy on a Jetty server through jetty runner. I inject properties read through a properties file using Spring. As of now, I have kept the properties file within the webapp itself (in WEB-INF/classes) directory. I want to keep this properties file external to the webapp and then inject them using Spring. Is there any configuration in the `jetty.xml` file I can do so I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the properties file as a command line parameter while starting jetty. Something like:

```
java -Dexternal.properties.file=myfile.properties -jar jetty.jar
```

In java code, I read it by getting system property and then using FileUtils to get file.

```
String externalPropertiesFile = System.getProperty("extern.properties.file");
File file = FileUtils.getFile(externalPropertiesFile);
```